# Reactjs + Active Directory groups (React, Express, Node-SSPI)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, active-directory, windows-authentication

I'm working on my company's intranet site. We are a fairly large company and have a full active directory for multiple departments and access levels per department. I'm trying to tap into the Active Directory groups we already have in places for auth on the site.

I have made up a mockup app at https://github.com/Gmunker/fetcherror. Essentially all I need is to use React to fetch the users' names and an array of their groups in Active Directory. I'm using React with a fetch to an Express server which is using node-sspi to grab the users' info. I can access the endpoint directly in the browser at http://localhost:3001/adauth, but when I try and fetch, I get a 401.

Comment: The 401 Unauthorized Error is an HTTP response status code indicating that the request sent by the client could not be authenticated. When you try from the browser, you are getting the result because the proxy is already setup and browser is making use of that. But, when you make the same request from React, you will have to pass authentication data as the part of request header.

Comment: So is there a way to push the "Windows Credentials" for the auth? Since they need to use their domain login they are essentially authenticated at that point.

Comment: I think it can help you. [Node in Corporative Environment with NODESSPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498789/node-in-corporative-environment-with-nodesspi)